# Fancybox causes scroll bars to appear

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have used fancybox successfully before, but on my latest design, fancybox causes scroll bars to appear, i.e. clicking on the image, the image gets displayed in the middle of the window and the window itself gets scroll bars it didn't use to have. My layout is fluid and adjusts, when one changes the window size or font size. Using fancybox, then, the whole page shifts and rescales for no apparent reason, which looks bad and also uses processor power.

What could be the cause of this?

Also, the background fails to be darkened off... What does fancybox do to achieve this usually, and why would it fail with my design?

Here are some code snippets:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.fancybox').fancybox();
});
</script>

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="classes" class="post">
<h2>料理教室・ワークショップ</h2>
<a class="fancybox" rel="classes" href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-content/themes/hitomiskuche/images/classes/1.jpg">フォトス</a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="classes" href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-content/themes/hitomiskuche/images/classes/2.jpg"></a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="classes" href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-content/themes/hitomiskuche/images/classes/3.jpg"></a>
</div>
</div>

#classes {
    width:40%;
    position:absolute;
    left:5%;
    bottom:10%;
    background-color:#fff;
    padding:1em;
    opacity:0.65;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 3px #555;
}
```

Comment: fiddle or code please....might be the inclusion of another class or the wrapper class around your fancybox div

Comment: @rizwaniqbal I've included some code. Is this enough to tell what's going wrong?

Comment: Have you fixed this? Can you accept an answer?

Comment: @PimSchaaf Neither answer did fix the issue, which is why I didn't accept either.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers : {
        overlay : {
            locked : false
        }
    }
});
```

And if you're using a full-screen background like 'supersized', you may want to add this to the css of your page as well:

```
html {overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; overflow: scroll;}
```

Answer (score 1):

as answered by Rob and Eva adding helper code to java script conf works for me

here is my full code

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".fancybox").fancybox({
                maxWidth        : 800,
                maxHeight   : 500,
                fitToView       : true,
                width       : '100%',
                height      : '100%',
                autoSize        : true,
                closeClick      : true,
                openEffect  : 'elastic',
                closeEffect : 'elastic',
                helpers : {
                overlay : {
                    locked : false
                }
            }

            });
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Fancybox uses the class `fancybox-overlay` to display the overlay :

```
.fancybox-lock .fancybox-overlay {
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

The `overflow-y:scroll` property is making the scroll bar appear. Take it out and you will be sorted.

Also, you might not have included the `fancybox_overlay.png` in the same folder as the fancybox css file. The overlay background is created from this file. Hope this information helps

Comment: Doesn't make any difference